# How to have tablelayout not exceed certain space limit (not push other views off screen)

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there a way to limit how big a tablelayout/scroll view can get so that what ever view that comes after is not hidden?

For example, I have the following XML below an the first TextView and button are wrap contents so they will occupy a certain space. Now the Scroll/View table has its rows dynamically added ( and can get big or can be 0 rows). The last linearlayout has to be shown at all time. So Ideally I want the linearlayout to occupy 10% of the screen and whatever left (after the allocating the first Textview and button space) is allocated for tablelayout/scrollview.

Is there a way to do that? When the table is empty the linear layout should push up and not stay at the bottom of the screen. I have tried using weights but it seems I am just not getting it

```
<TextView ..../>
<Button ..../>
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableLayout           
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:shrinkColumns="*"
            android:stretchColumns="*" >
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        >
              <TextView
                    ... />  
              <TextView
                    ... />                                     

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you'll be surprised to know but it is just very simple.Just put your scrollview between the button and the linear layout. Use `android:layout_below` and `android:layout_above` to achieve this. Keep everything `wrap_content`.

Comment: This will still push the linearlayout below